# How to kill a process in Linux if kill -9 has no effect

Tags: kill

I imagine that kill -9 still just sends a signal to a process. If the process is not behaving well, I would imagine that kill -9 would have no effect. Indeed, today for the first time I saw kill -9 have no effect when sent to a stuck ruby process. So here is my question: Is there some harsher way to kill a process?

Comment: You mention Ruby here, and I am curious what the pieces are that you are dealing with.  I was using Webrick and had a similar experience, I started using `Rack::Server.new` and the processes were handled correctly, and would thereafter respond to `control-c`.

Comment: vgoff, I will have to collect more information on the process. Let me get back to you on that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to reboot the machine. If `kill -9` doesn't kill a process, that means it is stuck in the kernel. Unless you can figure out what it's stuck on and unstick it, there's nothing you can do. The reason it's stuck is that it is waiting for something and the logic necessary to cleanly stop waiting simply doesn't exist.

(The above assumes the process has already been reparented to `init`. Otherwise, its parent may be keeping it around. You may have to kill its parent.)

Comment: +1 like the answer. What I have found is it's often stuck on waiting for a parent that's already dead. A zombie won't take up memory, but it can fill up the process table if you have 1000s and occupy ports it's bound to.

Comment: A zombie process shouldn't be able to occupy ports. When the process terminates, all its file descriptors should be closed even before it's reaped. At least, that's what I'd always assumed.

Comment: You may be right. I can't verify for certain, but at least it was (were) process(es) that couldn't be killed with kill -9 occupying a port.

Comment: FWIW, I had a stuck process that even had an open windows that wouldn’t close (frozen). SIGPWR didn’t help either, I had to reboot (Ubuntu 20.04 beta).

Answer (score 11):

Every time I have a job that is stuck and signals 9 or 15 won't kill it, I send it signal 30 (SIGPWR) and almost every single time it will clear it out. I can't recall when sending the power outage signal didn't work.

Comment: Wow, it helped!

Comment: don't work for me, I mistakenly typed cat /**/* as root. And I can never kill it again

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is, a reboot...

Normally though being unable to **kill -9** a process is not such a problem since these processes are not doing much to hog your system, they're probably just zombies. The only time it necessitated me to reboot in order to get rid of it is when it was "occupying" a tcp port I needed to use.